# wordpress query_posts - pass 2 meta value with order by 1 meta value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
global $wp_query; $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'meta_value' => 'pro') );
```

query_posts( $args );

i have 2 meta value pro and free i want to pass both in query/ or i want it order by pro with random order. i try to use , coma but not getting any solution .

```
query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand'); i pass this but i got all value random but what i want. i want pro first and then free
```

i pass this in in built theme. so when i pass pro i got pro value and when i pass free i got free value but i want both with pro list display first then free list and its random. order.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress post query you can order your posts by meta value. So, you can order with your meta key/values (0-9) or (A-Z).
You will use (A-Z) sorting.

```
$query = array( 'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC' );
```